# Is this mold in my furnace humidifer?

Tags: hvac, mold, humidifier

I recently purchased a home and noticed this inside my furnace's humidifier:

[image: humidifier]

[image: humidifier]

The home has been vacant for at least 6 months, and I hope that this is only due to it sitting unused for so long.

It is very dry and I could wipe it away like it was dust, but didn't want to disturb it anymore in case it was black mold.

If I clean the interior with bleach based cleaner, is that sufficient enough for it to be safe?

If these pictures aren't clear enough I can try to take better ones.

Thank You

Comment: You need to have it tested to tell if some type of mold or not.  Bleach or similar will kill mold, and clean off if just dirt/dust.  Wear a mask if dirt or mold.

Comment: If it is mold, it does not look like enough to be a health hazard, yet. As mentioned, cleaning with **dilute** bleach and water should be sufficient.